# How make a Maven package using JPA, but independent of service provider; and later how to plug in my service provider by user of this package?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, jpa, maven

I'm not sure if it's even possible...

I have some design patterns, which I want in my special Maven package (#1) - all these patterns use **javax.persistence**. I don't want this package to depend on Hibernate or any other implementation of JPA. Just let it depend on JPA API, as it is defined by JCP.
My second Maven package (#2) is to use this first one, and to specify which JPA implementation to use (f.e. Hibernate).

Now, how do I define my pom.xml for both of these packages (let JPA implementer for #2 package be Hibernate)?

Comment: What is the specific challenge that you have?  You only declare those dependencies in your pom which your project needs. So you would not have hibernate in package (#1), just JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA defines a package `javax.persistence`, it contains Annotations, Interfaces and so on. This package is completely Provider independent. It should contains every thing you need to implement provider independent services basd on JPA.

The only thing you need is to put an dependency to an `javax.persistence` containing maven artifact in your Maven module #1.

There are several maven artifacts containing this `javax.persistence` package. For example:

```
<dependency>
  <!-- JPA 1.0 -->
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <!-- JPA 2.0 -->
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In you Maven Module #2 you need to put an dependency to Module #1 and an dependency to the JPA provider (for example Hibernate) you like to use.
(If the provider you use, use an other dependency to the `javax.persistence` package, then you need to exclude one of them.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want Hibernate to be in the compilation path (to prevent developers from using vendor specific extensions), but you still want to have it packaged in the final artifact, you should use the `<scope>runtime</scope>` when defining your JPA implementation.